# Converting SQL group by and order by to Linq using case

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a Group by and Order by in an sql query as below ,how to write the same logic in linq? :-

```
  GROUP BY bd.bandcharge_desc, bd.rate 
  ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN bd.bandcharge_desc LIKE '%above%' THEN 
             '1' 
           ELSE 
             '0' 
           END,
           bd.bandcharge_desc,bd.rate ASC
```

Comment: Why zero (0) and one (1) is between single qoutes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: I tried like this:  orderby g.Key.bandcharge_desc Like '*/above/*'  ? 1 : 0 descending      what I tried is not working, also I don't think it may be a duplicate because the like in case palys an important role in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
orderby bd.bandcharge_desc.Contains("above")?1:0 descending ,
               bd.bandcharge_desc,bd.rate
```

Comment: it is giving me error:  Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'contain' and no extension method 'contain' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). using System.Linq is there in c# file.

Comment: I see it is a type, using Contains made it work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A try:

```
.OrderBy(bd => bd.bandcharge_desc.Contains("above") ? 1 : 0)
.ThenBy(bd => bd.bandcharge_desc)
.ThenBy(bd => bd.rate)
.GroupBy(bd => new {bd.bandcharge_desc, bd.rate})
```